# What command 'expo start -c' actually do?

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't run my app using 'expo start', but -c option can run it wuthout some errors. I didn't find this in --help opntion, so can you help to know this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running expo with the command `expo start -c` clears the cache.

https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/already-used-react-native/#useful-commands

Although it is not clearly explained here you can see that the following command takes the -c flag

`expo start -c --localhost --ios`

Their explanation is

> start expo server, clear cache, load only on localhost and open on iOS simulator

So following the order of the flags it is clear that the -c flag clears the cache. That is why your errors will disappear as the cache has been cleaned.